# Intelij Gradle error build target

Tags: android, gradle

I made new android proiect in intelij 14.0.1 and i get this error

Error:Android Gradle Build Target: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation '/home/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.1-all/6n6ckv1svbjkm5ebj9is3php05/gradle-2.1'.

I can't find any solution?

in build.gradle i set
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is in your `JAVA` path. Check project structure ( Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S ) and add your java JDK to the Project SDK. The path should point to `jdk` directory and not to `jre`

Comment: Thanks, this help me but why there is this problem? Something wrong with my local path in linux?